# How to update time stamp when the ActiveX checkbox is both checked and unchecked

Tags: excel, vba

I have a checkbox that I want to time stamp `NOW()` when selected to indicate when the decision to activate was made.  I'd like to deselect the checkbox when the decision to deactivate is made and have an updated time stamp to reflect the time of that decision.

Would it be simpler to use two radio buttons with "activate" and "deactivate," then updating the time stamp based on that selection?

My checkbox has the following code. It puts the time stamp in, and then copies the value to the cell to keep the time from automatically updating.

```vb
Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()
'ER Runner

    If ActiveSheet.CheckBox3.Value = True Then
        Me.Cells(47, 33).Value = True
    Else
        Me.Cells(47, 33).Value = False
    End If
    
    If ActiveSheet.CheckBox3.Value = True Then
        Me.Cells(47, 24) = Now()
        Range("X47").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
          :=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("X47:AD47").Merge
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: "an updated time stamp" - where? In another cell? Sounds like you are doing the same thing when the box is ticked or unticked?

Comment: Basically, if x is in A1 and the time stamp is B1.  Then when the checkbox for x is selected, a time stamp is entered and the checkbox sub assigns a true to... say C1.  So on a separate sheet, a log is being prepared.  It recognizes if C1 is true, then that time stamp is for activation.  If unticked and C1 is false, the log sheet recognizes the time stamp is now for a deactivation.  Ideally if it's possible and if I could figure it out, I'd like a running log of actions... I suppose the time stamp does not need to be on the entry sheet as long as it is posted in the log.  That might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

There is some unnecessary action in your code. When writing *the value* of `Now()` to a cell, you don't need to copy/paste special as it's not a formula you're writing.

Trying to keep as much of the logic from your code as possible, I think it boils down to the following:

```
Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()
'ER Runner

    Me.Cells(47, 24) = Now()
    Me.Cells(47, 33).Value = Me.CheckBox3.Value
    Me.Range("X47:AD47").Merge
    Me.Cells(47, 33).Value = False
     
End Sub
```

However, if the merge command should only run when the value is True, you'll need to use an If statement to conditionalise that.